# positive numbers only - formik/yup schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I made such a schema:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({

    seats: yup
      .number()
      .label('seats')
      .required('pls enter'),
  });
```

Additionally, I want to check that the number is positive or greater than 0. Is there any way I can add such a condition into the schema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `test()` method and add a custom validation there:

```
number: Yup.number()
  .required('ERROR: The number is required!')
  .test(
    'Is positive?', 
    'ERROR: The number must be greater than 0!', 
    (value) => value > 0
  )
```

https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema

Comment: This gives me an ```Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.``` error on value even tho I have added the required method

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to take that into account. In this case you can change it to something like
```
(value) => value === undefined || value === null || value > 0
``` 
for example (|| instead of && so that the `required` errors are not caught by this test)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `.positive()` and also `.min(1)`

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({

    seats: yup
      .number()
      .positive()
      .label('seats')
      .required('pls enter')
      .min(1),
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually Yup provides this out of the box with: https://github.com/jquense/yup#numberpositivemessage-string--function-schema